# How to sign out when using gapi.auth2.authorize

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am using gapi.auth2.authorize to authorize people in my Google Photos API app but I cannont find a why to unauthorize or disconnect them from the app. What I have noticed though is that there is no way of using an old access token so that the user doesn't need to authorize.

How can I make the access token invalid?

Is it correct that every time the API is used the user has to authorize?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
How can I make the access token invalid?
```

Not possible to invalidate an access token, it will expire after 1h

You can check documenttation [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth)

```
Is it correct that every time the API is used the user has to authorize?
```

Nope, you should ask users to authorize only once, using a refresh token that you can keep in your back-end, thus allowing your app to content on on users behalf all the time, until they revoke permissions